# Delete prevention trigger not working - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I created this trigger for a flight booking database where the trigger is meant to prevent reserved bookings from being deleted when using a delete sql statement. I have two statuses. One is 'r' for reserved and the other is 'c' for cancelled. My mission is to ensure that reserved bookings cannot be deleted and if a user tries to delete one, it raises the exception that's shown in my example trigger.

I have created this trigger and it has executed successfully but when I test it by deleting a reserved booking with status 'r' it runs and says "query returned successfully: one row affected..." which is not what I want. I want it to raise the exception and not delete the booking.

```
CREATE FUNCTION prevent_deletion() RETURNS trigger AS $prevent_deletion$

        BEGIN            
            IF 'status' = 'r' THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'You cannot delete reserved bookings';
            END IF;
            RETURN NEW;

        END;
    $prevent_deletion$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    CREATE TRIGGER prevent_deletion AFTER DELETE ON flightbooking
        FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE prevent_deletion();
```

Comment: You need a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger.

Comment: @J.Doe: In a `BEFORE` trigger, the triggering operation is aborted if you return `NULL`, and `NEW` is `NULL` in your case (there's no "new" record for a `DELETE`). Try `RETURN OLD` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
IF 'status' = 'r' THEN
```

...compares the string `'status'` to the string `'r'` (and of course, they're never going to be equal...).

Comparing the *field* `status` to the string `'r'` would look like this:

```
IF OLD.status = 'r' THEN
```